# Convert RFC 3339 date to dd-M-yyyy in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a large table returning data from solr, I can't do anything server side so I need to use client side javascript and the date format emitted is:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

Lovely. I want it to display as:

```
dd-M-yyyy (or 21-Jan-2011, for example)
```

Each date is in a td with a class of "formatdate". I thought something like this (below) would work, sitting inside a

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

and format everything "automagically", but no such luck;

```
$('.formatdate').each(function() {
var date = document.getElementByClassName('formatdate');
$(".formatdate").innerHTML = new Date(date);
});
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: The other side of this is, inserting this

```
"mRender": function(date, type, full) { return new Date(date).toDateString(); }
```

into datatables returns "Fri Nov 2 2012", but then I have zero formatting options - it really has to be "02-Nov-2012"... Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, the format `21-Jan-2011` is marked as `dd-Mmm-yyyy` (3 characters in month as in short name of month).

Comment: In jQuery, dateFormat is noted as dd-M-yyyy.

Comment: Could be, but if you look it up, you'll find more results with `dd-Mmm-yyyy`, this notation is used in Java, C#, databases, etc.

Comment: Totally understand, but I have to keep client-side for this one! Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hC242/1).

```
$(".formatdate").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        date = $this.html();
    $this.html(new Date(date));
});
```

Comment: Hi Bram! Thank you for the quick reply, unfortunately no luck, the tr and td's are loaded in dom (via dataTables), and while it works ok-ish in the fiddle (format is way off) it doesn't format in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are basically saying this:

- For each `.formatdate`...

  - Get the collection of `.formatdate` elements
  - Create a date from them (???)
  - Put that date in all `.formatdate` elements.

Needless to say, it's not what you intended!

Try this:

```
var months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
$(".formatdate").each(function() {
    var dateparts = this.firstChild.nodeValue.match(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/);

    this.firstChild.nodeValue =
       dateparts[2] + "-"
       + months.substr((dateparts[1]-1)*3,3) + "-"
       + dateparts[0];
});
```

Comment: Hi Niet (or Mr. the Dark Absol), thank you for the quick reply, no such luck though, btw, I'm in IE9 for this mess, but it errors out with: Unable to get value of the property '2': object is null or undefined...

Comment: Hmm... could you have it show you the result of `this.firstChild.nodeValue`, please?

Comment: text inside the node is "2012-11-02T05:00:00Z" - is that what you meant? Also, the tr's are added via dom, and we're talking older IE browsers, 8,9 here. Thank you; I get this happening, I can actually relax today!

Comment: Is that what `alert(this.firstChild.nodeValue)` reports to you?

Comment: oh. gotcha, actually, that returned null.

Comment: Okay... what does `alert(this.firstChild)` give, then?

Comment: Comes back with [object DocumentType]